# Fill coordinate points using data imported from a shapefile in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript

I have uploaded a shapefile to google earth engine and imported it as a table.  From the table column, how do I color the coordinate points with respect to the temp_f values that are listed in the uploaded table. This is what I have so far,

```
var shp = ee.FeatureCollection(temps).limit(5);
var temperatures = shp.select('temp_f');
print(temperatures);
//Temperature parameters
var palette_1 = ee.List(['white', 'blue', 'red']);
var Thermal_vis = ee.Dictionary({
   min: 80,
   max: 89,
   palette: palette_1,
   properties: ['temp_f']
});
Map.addLayer(temperatures,Thermal_vis,'temps');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vector features can be colored according to an attribute by "painting" the features onto an image object as follows:

```js
// Copyright 2022 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

// Buffer each feature so it is visible.
var radius = 2e2;
var buffered = shp.map(function(f) {return f.buffer(radius)});

// Paint an image with colors defined by a feature attribute.
var empty = ee.Image().byte();
var fills = empty.paint({
  featureCollection: buffered,
  color: 'temp_f'
});

// Display the image on the map.
var ThermalVis = {
  min:80,
  max:89,
  palette: ['white', 'blue', 'red']
};
Map.addLayer(fills, ThermalVis, 'temps (visualization)');
```

Here is the link to the code:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/272178890fd0ea03be1641d60aca740f

More options for styling features can be found in the [Feature and FeatureCollection Visualization](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/feature_collections_visualizing) section of the Earth Engine documentation.